# Stastics Probability

Tags: probability

Suppose we draw two cards from a deck of playing cards. What is the probability of drawing two spades P(two spades)?

1. a. P(*two spades*) = $\frac{1}{26}$
2. b. P(*two spades*) = $3\cdot\frac{1}{51}$
3. c. P(*two spades*) = $\frac{2}{52}$
4. d. P(*two spades*) = $\frac{1}{16}$

Is it A, please help thanks

Comment: Is this homework? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes, I get 2/52 whichs gives me 1/26 but am I correct?

Comment: In how many can the first spade be chosen, out of how many total number of ways? similarly, what about the second? Now, both the events are independent, so what is the net probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of ways to pick two cards is $C(52, 2)$, and the number of ways to pick two spades is $C(13,2)$

Thus the probability is $\frac{C(13,2)}{C(52,2)}$, which is equal to 1/17

Comment: wow I didn't know we could use combinations in here, number of outcomes/total outcomes makes sense thank you very much